# How to display a video error in Angular12

Tags: html, angular, typescript, video, error-handling

My goal is to display a user readable error when a video file gets corrupted. I found this block of code which is perfect for my use case but i can't seem to get it to work ...
I even tried to put it in pure JS directly in the template but it still doesn't work.

My html:

```
<nb-card>

<video src="tgif.vid"
  autoplay
  controls
  onerror="errorMessageVideo(event)">
</video>

</nb-card>
```

My Ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-video-card',
  templateUrl: './video-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-card.component.scss']
})
export class VideoCardComponent implements OnInit  {

ngOnInit() {
  this.errorMessageVideo(Event);
}
  errorMessageVideo(e) {
    // video playback failed - show a message saying why
    switch (e.target.error.code) {
      case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
        alert('You aborted the video playback.');
        break;
      case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
        alert('A network error caused the video download to fail part-way.');
        break;
      case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
        alert('The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.');
        break;
      case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        alert('The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.');
        break;
      default:
        alert('An unknown error occurred.');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me please

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your template.

You need to bind the event with parentheses and change the name of the error event in the template. And also you need to pass the event with `$event` instead of `event` as following:

```
<video src="tgif.vid"
  autoplay
  controls
  (error)="errorMessageVideo($event)">
</video>
```